# Trouble with LED dimmable bulbs in fan

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, led

I recently purchased LED candelabras to replace my incandescent bulbs in my fan. When I installed just one bulb everything worked perfect (fully dimmable/full power). I didn't like the color temperature difference between the old and new so I replaced the second bulb with another LED. Now neither bulb turns on. If I replace either LED with an incandescent, everything works again. What's going on that I can't have LEDs in each socket?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Sounds like your dimmer isn't LED compatible. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What make and model is your dimmer/wall control, or are you using a fan remote for that?

Comment: Fan remote. Any way to change the dimmer in the fan? Or just use incandescent? I was trying to get brighter bulbs but can't with incandescent due to wattage restrictions.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the fan/light please?  Are you open to switching out your current fan remote for something else, for that matter?